# React geted results diplay in console but not on screen

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I have this react component with calendar from react-multi-date-picker package:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Calendar } from "react-multi-date-picker";
import { getAllFilledJournauxDates } from '../../services/JournauxService';


export default function Test() {
  
  const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

  const getDates = async () => {
    const rec = await getAllFilledJournauxDates();
    setDates(rec);
    console.log(dates);
    console.log(rec);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getDates();
  }
  , [])

  return(
    <div>
      <Calendar 
        fullYear
        multiple
        value={dates}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

i ask the datas with this function that i call in my test component :

```
export async function getAllFilledJournauxDates() {
    
        let dates = [];
        let journaux = getAllJournaux()
            .then(response => {
                Object.keys(response).forEach(element => {
                    dates.push(new Date(new Date(response[element].date)).getFullYear() + "-" + (new Date(response[element].date)).getMonth() + "-" + (new Date(response[element].date)).getDate());
                })
            })
        return dates;
}
```

when i run it in my console i cant get the value i want, but nothing on the calendar,
can you see what i doing wrong ?
thanks by advance and have a great coding day.

Comment: Try something other than that calendar component. Something like this:
```
<div>{dates.map((date, key) => <h1 key={key}>{date.toString()}</h1>)</div>
```
This will tell you if data is getting passed to the calendar component. If it *is* then there is something wrong with the calendar component.

Comment: setDates is an async function so the effect is not immediate 

Add 
```useEffect(()=>{
console.log(dates);
},[dates])```

Comment: @BenMcLean981 i get [object Promise] on my screen , in console the promise is at fullfilled state, and i can browse the data in  the object, but don't understand how i can make them available for my calendar

Comment: @vatsalsoni alway the value in console but nothing on screen

Comment: you can use just `new Date(date)` when pushing https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-date-picker-forked-d1cdou?file=/src/App.js take a look at this